# Why does the following function not have a minimum?

Tags: calculus, functions

Consider the following function

[image]

I am asked to explain why the function doesn't have a minimum.

My rough attempt: the closer $x$ gets to $1$ (from the right side), the smaller the output is. But no matter how close $x$ gets to $1$, we always can find value that will be even closer. Hence there is no minimum.

Now, can someone provide me with more rigorous answer to the question, please?

Comment: That is a rigorous answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x\in[-2,2]$ we have $f(x)>-1,$ but for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $x\in[-2,2]$,

for which $f(x)<-1+\epsilon,$ which says that $f$ has no minimal value.

Answer (score 0):

$x^{\star}$ is said to be a local minimum of $f$ if $$\exists \epsilon>0\:\:\forall x\in B(x^{\star},\epsilon)\:\:f(x^{\star})\leq f(x)$$ So in this one dimensional example we have $B(x^{\star},\epsilon)=(x^{\star}-\epsilon,x^{\star}+\epsilon)$. Now suppose that $f$ has a local minimum at $x^{\star}$. If $x^{\star}>1$, then for $f(x^{\star}-\frac{\epsilon}{2})$ we have contradiciton. If $x^{\star}\leq1$, then for $f(x^{\star}+\frac{\epsilon}{2})$ we have contradiction.